# How to increase progressbar while downloading file using Sftp (C#)

Tags: c#, sftp

This code execute well. But didn't increase progressBar1.value

```cs
using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var sftpFileStream = client.OpenRead(remoteFilePath);
        var fileLength = client.GetAttributes(remoteFilePath).Size;
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        var totalBytesRead = 0L;
        var bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = sftpFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            var progress = (double)totalBytesRead / fileLength;
            progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
            });
        }
                    }
        client.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

I tried without Invoke

```
...
...
var progress = (double)totalBytesRead / fileLength;
progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
```

Both way didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: With your code, the value runs from 0.0 to 1.0. What are the Min/Max values of your ProgressBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the value of the progress bar within the range 0.0 to 1.0: `progress = (double)totalBytesRead / fileLength;`. This has to match the mininum and maximum value as set at the progress bar control. So

- either set the maximum value of the progress bar control to 1
- or leave it at 100 and set the value as `progress = 100.0 * totalBytesRead / fileLength;`